# Finding data from Table A and Table B relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

By see below tables how to (write query) get `Table A` data and `status = InActive` with no Data in `Table B`

Example : `4   Comm4           InActive`

```
Table A

AID  Name           Status
--  ---             --
1   comm1           Active
2   comm2           Active
3   Comm3           InActive
4   Comm4           InActive
5   Comm5           InActive


 Table B

 BID  Name  AID
 ---  ----  ---
  11  James 1
  12  Kris  2
  13  Dan   3
  14  Steve 3
  15  Brian 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple

```
select * from tableA
where status = 'InActive'
and not exists (select * from tableB where tableA.AID = tableB.AID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tableA.* 
  from tableA 
  left join tableB 
    on tableA.AID = tableB.AID 
   and tableA.status = 'InActive' 
 where tableB.AID is null
```

The not exists from Szymon is correct and may be more efficient

Answer (score -1):

Here you try.

```
select *
from #table_one
where Status = 'InActive'
and not exists
(
    select 1 from #table_two where AID = #table_one.AID
);
```